# encountered ")." was expecting one of "as" in teradata

Tags: teradata

I am getting above mentioned error while executing a query against Teradata Studio express

```
select 
       Union16.Item  as  Item,
       Union16.Description  as  Description,
       Union16.Nbr_Trans  as  Nbr_Trans,
       Union16.Unit_price  as  Unit_price,
       Union16.Amount  as  Amount,
      MIN(Union16.Amount) as  Total_Amount_

 from (select     AL1.ticket_document_number  as  ticket_document_number,
           AL1.transaction_code  as  transaction_code,
           AL1.void_status  as  void_status,
           AL1.transaction_date  as  transaction_date,
           AL1.pnr_record_locator  as  pnr_record_locator,
           AL1.settlement_base_fare_amt  as  settlement_base_fare_amt,
           AL1.settlement_total_tax_amt  as  settlement_total_tax_amt,
           AL1.Multiplier  as  Multiplier,
           (AL1.Multiplier * 2)  as  Service_Incentive_Fee,
           (AL1.Multiplier * 2)  as  Transaction_Fee,
           (case when AL1.TRANSACTION_CODE = 'ET' and AL1.VOID_STATUS = 'N' then 1
     when AL1.TRANSACTION_CODE = 'RF' and AL1.VOID_STATUS = 'N' then -1
    else 0
    end) as NetTrans,
           0  as  Comm_Amount,
           SUM(1) as  Total_Trans,
           AL1.period_end_date  as  period_end_date,
           SUM(NetTrans * 2)   as  Service_Fee_due,
           AL1.airline_code  as  airline_code,
           1  as  Item,
           (('Supplier Link Service Incentive Fee @ $' || '2') || '/Tix')  as  Description,
           2  as  Unit_price,
           SUM(NetTrans * 2)  as  Amount,
           SUM(NetTrans * 2)   as  Transaction_Fee_due,
           SUM((NetTrans * 2) + (NetTrans * 2))   as  Total_Due,
           SUM(1) as  Total_Total_Trans_,
           SUM(NetTrans * 2)  as  Total_Service_Fee_due_,
           SUM(NetTrans * 2)  as  Total_Transaction_Fee_due_,
           SUM((NetTrans * 2) + (NetTrans* 2))  as  Total_Total_Due_,
           SUM(NetTrans) as  Net_Trans,
           SUM(NetTrans)  as  Total_Net_Trans_,
           SUM(NetTrans)  as  Nbr_Trans

     from  (SELECT LAST_DAY(AL1.period_end_date) AS PEDHEADER,
    AL1.TICKET_DOCUMENT_NUMBER as TICKET_DOCUMENT_NUMBER ,
(case when AL1.TRANSACTION_CODE = 'ET' and AL1.VOID_STATUS = 'N' then 1
     when AL1.TRANSACTION_CODE = 'RF' and AL1.VOID_STATUS = 'N' then -1
    else 0
    end) as NetTrans,

       (case
    when AL1.VOID_STATUS = 'V' then 0
    when AL1.VOID_STATUS <> 'V' and AL1.TRANSACTION_CODE in ('AT','ET') then 1
    when  AL1.VOID_STATUS <> 'V' and AL1.TRANSACTION_CODE = 'RF' then -1
    when  AL1.VOID_STATUS <> 'V' and AL1.TRANSACTION_CODE not in ('AT','ET','RF') then 0
    end
    ) as Multiplier,
    AL1.TRANSACTION_CODE as TRANSACTION_CODE , 
    AL1.VOID_STATUS as VOID_STATUS, 
    cast(AL1.TRANSACTION_DATE as date) as TRANSACTION_DATE , 
    AL1.PNR_RECORD_LOCATOR as PNR_RECORD_LOCATOR , 
    AL1.SETTLEMENT_BASE_FARE_AMT as SETTLEMENT_BASE_FARE_AMT , 
    AL1.SETTLEMENT_TOTAL_TAX_AMT as  SETTLEMENT_TOTAL_TAX_AMT, 
    cast(AL1.PERIOD_END_DATE as date) as PERIOD_END_DATE , 
    AL1.AIRLINE_CODE as AIRLINE_CODE,
    airline_name as  airline_name ,
       SUM (1 )  as  Total_records,
       0  as  Total_comm_due,
       SUM ((Multiplier * 2) )  as  total_serv_inc_fee,
       SUM ((Multiplier * 2) )  as  total_trans_fee_due,
       ((0 + SUM((Multiplier * 2) )) + SUM((Multiplier * 2) ))  as  Total_amt_due,

                 0  as  Comm_Amount,
       (Multiplier * 2)  as  Service_Incentive_Fee,
       (Multiplier * 2)  as  Transaction_Fee,
       1  as  cntr
    FROM ODS_VIEWS.BOP_ARC_SETTLEMENT AL1 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (select tabC.refvalcode, tabC.acct_cd, tabC.airline_name, tabC.refvaltm
     from  (select ref1.refvalcode , max(case when ref1.refvalattribcode='numericCode' then ref1.refvalvalue else null end) as acct_cd,
                   max(case when ref1.refvalattribcode='Codedescription' then ref1.refvalvalue else null end) as airline_name,
                   tabA.refvaltm
            from   bial.refvalue ref1, (select refvalcode, refvalvalue as airline_name, max(refvalueid) as "refvaltm"
                                      from bial.refvalue
                                      where  refvalcodesetcode='Carrier' 
                                      and refvalattribcode='Codedescription'
                                      group by refvalcode, refvalvalue) tabA
            where  tabA.refvalcode = ref1.refvalcode
            and ref1.refvalcodesetcode='Carrier' 
            group by ref1.refvalcode, tabA.refvaltm ) tabC
    ,
            (select tabB.acct_cd, max(tabB.refvaltm) as "refvaltm"
              from  (select ref1.refvalcode , max(case when ref1.refvalattribcode='numericCode' then ref1.refvalvalue else null end) as acct_cd,
                            max(case when ref1.refvalattribcode='Codedescription' then ref1.refvalvalue else null end) as airline_name,tabA.refvaltm
                     from bial.refvalue ref1, (select refvalcode, refvalvalue as airline_name, max(refvalueid) as "refvaltm"
                                                     from bial.refvalue
                                                     where refvalcodesetcode='Carrier' 
                                                     and refvalattribcode='Codedescription'
                                                     group by refvalcode, refvalvalue) tabA
                     where tabA.refvalcode = ref1.refvalcode 
                     and ref1.refvalcodesetcode='Carrier' 
                     group by ref1.refvalcode, tabA.refvaltm ) tabB
    group by tabB.acct_cd
    ) tabD
 where tabC.refvaltm = tabD.refvaltm
    and tabC.acct_cd = tabD.acct_cd
) AIRDET
    ON AL1.AIRLINE_CODE = AIRDET.acct_cd
    WHERE cast(AL1.PERIOD_END_DATE as date) BETWEEN  01-01-2015 AND 31-01-2015
    AND AL1.FILE_TYPE='AM' 
    AND AL1.SUPPLIER_LINK_INDICATOR='D' 
    AND AIRLINE_NAME = 'Alaska Airlines'

    AND AL1.oltp_deleted_timestamp IS NULL

    group by 
AL1.period_end_date ,
    AL1.TICKET_DOCUMENT_NUMBER,
NetTrans  ,
Multiplier ,
    AL1.TRANSACTION_CODE, 
    AL1.VOID_STATUS, 
    AL1.TRANSACTION_DATE, 
    AL1.PNR_RECORD_LOCATOR, 
    AL1.SETTLEMENT_BASE_FARE_AMT, 
    AL1.SETTLEMENT_TOTAL_TAX_AMT,  
    AL1.AIRLINE_CODE,
    airline_name, 
       Total_comm_due,
     Comm_Amount,
         Service_Incentive_Fee,
         Transaction_Fee,
        cntr,
AL1.oltp_deleted_timestamp,
AL1.SUPPLIER_LINK_INDICATOR,
AL1.FILE_TYPE,
AL1.AIRLINE_CODE
)
 ) Union16
 group by 
       Union16.Item,
       Union16.Description,
       Union16.Nbr_Trans,
       Union16.Unit_price,
       Union16.Amount
 order by 
       Item asc,
       Description asc;
```

Comment: We are not human compilers.  Strip out code to a minimal, working query, then add back in until you find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you have close look at the query editor. You will notice that Teradata Studio marks the position of the error.

There's an alias missing for the Derived Table before `) Union16`